# Visual Studio 2022 - Web.config is reverting back when building the solution

Tags: .net, web-config, settings, visual-studio-2022, revert

I am changing a header policy in my `web.config` file. I add the line:

```
<add name="Referrer-Policy"> value="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" />
```

and save the file.

Now when I build the .NET Framework 4.8 solution, the `web.config` file just reverts back to the original file without the line. I don't have any pre-build events in the Build->Events section of project properties.

Also, this file is a `.gitignore` file in my project.
I don't have any transform files  either in my project directory.

Does anyone have some troubleshooting tips for this?